# How to check if previous query was executed correctly?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, transactions

I have to decrease money from a user account and increase another user account, namely to transfer money from an account to another.
I have this code for example, in MySql:

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE accounts
SET balance = (balance-100)
WHERE account_id = 2 AND balance>100;

--If the above query is succesfully then:
UPDATE accounts
SET balance = (balance+100)
WHERE account_id =1;

--How can I exec the commit only if everything is ok?
COMMIT;
```

The first query is executed only if the balance>100.

However the second query (namely the second update) should be executed only if the prevoious query has decreased the balance.  How could I automatically check this?

Furthermore the COMMIT;   has to be executed only if the previous 2 queries have done their job.

How could this be implemented?

(I'm using PHP too but I think this problem could easily tackled using sql. Am I wrong?)

Comment: Define according [CONTINUE HANDLER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/declare-handler.html), set some flag variable in its code, analyse its value after statement execution does some error/warning was produced by previous statement(s). Do not forget to remove WHERE from 1st query but add `CHECK (balance >= 0)` constraint to the table definition which allows to detect the problem.

Comment: *The first query is executed only if the balance>100.* This is wrong !!! the query is executed anycase. It alters the data only when the condition met - this is true.

Comment: @Akina Of course I meant the change is executed only if the balance>100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform the operation as single query, not as a query pack:

```sql
UPDATE accounts t1
CROSS JOIN accounts t2
SET t1.balance = (t1.balance-100),
    t2.balance = (t2.balance+100)
WHERE t1.account_id = 2 AND t1.balance>100
  AND t2.balance_id = 1;

-- or

UPDATE accounts
SET balance = balance + CASE account_id WHEN 1 THEN 100
                                        WHEN 2 THEN -100 END
WHERE account_id IN (1,2);
```

And you do not need in transaction at all.

---

Also you may check the amount of rows altered (by fact, on disk, not formally) by previous query, and take this info into account in 2nd query:

```sql
START TRANSACTION;

UPDATE accounts
SET balance = (balance-100)
WHERE account_id = 2 AND balance>100;

UPDATE accounts
SET balance = (balance+100)
WHERE account_id =1 
  AND ROW_COUNT();  -- check does a row was altered in previous statement
                    -- if not then this statement will not alter any row too

COMMIT;
```

Comment: And what if a crash happens when the first set clause is executed? Is the whole operation rolled back?

Comment: @Umbert In the 1st option (in both variants) - if the query fail by any reason then none row will be updated. The query cannot update only one row from two rows matched - either all or none.

Comment: Thus more set clauses in a UPDATE all performed or none, that is, they have a kind of built-in transition.   Furthermore, the cross join (Cartesian product) in your first solution is needed to be able to refer both the tables in the SET?

Comment: @Umbert Single query is ALWAYS a transaction. Exclusion - stream macrofunctions (for example, LOAD DATA).